# How to diagnose repeated OS X hang / spinning ball of death?

Tags: mac, crash, performance, macos

I got this error with everyday tasks. I tried verifying disk, permission. fsck -fy - files has been modified, then disk is ok. I repaired keychain.

Do you have any idea what causes this problems? Nothing worked.

```
Process:         crsud [48]
Path:            /usr/libexec/crsud
Identifier:      crsud
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2015-02-21 14:22:30.286 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G63)
Report Version:  9

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: 0x000000000000000a, 0x0000000100784000

VM Regions Near 0x100784000:
    shared memory          0000000100783000-0000000100784000 [    4K] rw-/rw- SM=SHM  
--> mapped file            0000000100784000-000000010078c000 [   32K] r--/r-x SM=PRV  /private/var/db/*
    shared memory          000000010078c000-000000010078d000 [    4K] rw-/rw- SM=SHM  

Application Specific Information:
objc[48]: garbage collection is OFF

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.security              0x00007fff8829b278 Security::SharedMemoryClient::SharedMemoryClient(char const*, unsigned int) + 288
1   com.apple.security              0x00007fff8829b95c Security::ModuleNexus<Security::SecurityServer::SharedMemoryClientMaker>::make() + 59
2   com.apple.security              0x00007fff8813aeb4 Security::ModuleNexusCommon::create(void* (*)()) + 166
3   com.apple.security              0x00007fff8829b86d Security::ModuleNexus<Security::SecurityServer::SharedMemoryClientMaker>::operator()() + 71
4   com.apple.security              0x00007fff8829b72e Security::SecurityServer::NotificationPort::NotificationPort(unsigned int) + 40
5   com.apple.security              0x00007fff8829b79f Security::SecurityServer::ThreadNotifier::ThreadNotifier() + 79
6   com.apple.security              0x00007fff8816a91c Security::ThreadNexus<Security::SecurityServer::ThreadNotifier>::operator()() + 48
7   com.apple.security              0x00007fff881d9a3e Security::KeychainCore::CCallbackMgr::CCallbackMgr() + 32
8   com.apple.security              0x00007fff881d9ac2 CallbackMaker::CallbackMaker() + 44
9   com.apple.security              0x00007fff881d9b87 Security::ModuleNexus<CallbackMaker>::make() + 28
10  com.apple.security              0x00007fff8813aeb4 Security::ModuleNexusCommon::create(void* (*)()) + 166
11  com.apple.security              0x00007fff8819fcf5 Security::ModuleNexus<CallbackMaker>::operator()() + 71
12  com.apple.security              0x00007fff881d98fc Security::KeychainCore::CCallbackMgr::AddCallback(int (*)(unsigned int, SecKeychainCallbackInfo*, void*), unsigned int, void*) + 42
13  com.apple.security              0x00007fff88201cfd SecKeychainAddCallback + 29
14  com.apple.CFNetwork           0x00007fff87280a01 _CFURLProtocolInitHTTPProtocol + 17
15  com.apple.CFNetwork           0x00007fff872809d2 URLProtocolRegistry::URLProtocolRegistry() + 78
16  com.apple.CFNetwork           0x00007fff8728096b URLProtocol::InitClass() + 65
17  libsystem_c.dylib             0x00007fff871c5e06 pthread_once + 86
18  com.apple.CFNetwork           0x00007fff87280921 URLProtocol::Class() + 23
19  com.apple.CFNetwork           0x00007fff872808f1 _CFURLProtocolRegisterFoundationBridge + 30
20  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff902681b8 +[_NSCFURLProtocolBridge registerWithCFURLProtocol] + 118
21  libsystem_c.dylib             0x00007fff871c5e06 pthread_once + 86
22  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff90268033 +[NSURLProtocol(NSURLProtocolPrivate) _registeredClasses] + 23
23  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff90267e83 NSURLConnectionInit + 184
24  libsystem_c.dylib             0x00007fff871c5e06 pthread_once + 86
25  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff90371044 -[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionPrivate) _initWithRequest:delegate:usesCache:maxContentLength:startImmediately:connectionProperties:] + 62
26  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff90267dc5 -[NSURLConnection initWithRequest:delegate:] + 47
27  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9036f487 +[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:delegate:] + 56
28  crsud                         0x00000001000022d7 0x100000000 + 8919
29  crsud                         0x0000000100002e00 0x100000000 + 11776
30  crsud                         0x0000000100001ec2 0x100000000 + 7874
31  crsud                         0x0000000100001aaf 0x100000000 + 6831
32  crsud                         0x0000000100001951 0x100000000 + 6481
33  crsud                         0x0000000100001870 0x100000000 + 6256

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e81c7e6 kevent + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff8ce8f786 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 923
2   libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff8ce8e316 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 54

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e81c192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x00007fff871c8594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x00007fff871c9b85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e81c192 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib             0x00007fff871c8594 _pthread_wqthread + 758
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x00007fff871c9b85 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff90267fc5 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 317
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9025c72a -[NSThread main] + 68
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9025c6a2 __NSThread__main__ + 1575
3   libsystem_c.dylib             0x00007fff871c68bf _pthread_start + 335
4   libsystem_c.dylib             0x00007fff871c9b75 thread_start + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000100784000  rbx: 0x000000010078c000  rcx: 0x0000000100783fff  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000004  rsi: 0x0000000000008000  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbff020  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbfefe0
   r8: 0x0000000000000004   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x00007fff8e81ba1e  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x0000000102203a78  r13: 0x00007fff5fbfeff0  r14: 0x0000000000000004  r15: 0x0000000102203a60
  rip: 0x00007fff8829b278  rfl: 0x0000000000010203  cr2: 0x0000000100784000
Logical CPU: 6

Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x10000afff  crsud (??? - ???) <ABD7454B-0BB3-3A4E-9F74-98CF8975706D> /usr/libexec/crsud
    0x7fff63324000 -     0x7fff63358baf  dyld (195.6 - ???) <C58DAD8A-4B00-3676-8637-93D6FDE73147> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff869fa000 -     0x7fff86a35fff  libsystem_info.dylib (??? - ???) <35F90252-2AE1-32C5-8D34-782C614D9639> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x7fff86d5c000 -     0x7fff86d6eff7  libbsm.0.dylib (??? - ???) <349BB16F-75FA-363F-8D98-7A9C3FA90A0D> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
    0x7fff86d6f000 -     0x7fff86e79fe7  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (0.9.8 - compatibility 0.9.8) <0E7A4F63-035E-3406-AE8C-8F9E3E47D2EE> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff8704b000 -     0x7fff87051fff  libmacho.dylib (800.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <165514D7-1BFA-38EF-A151-676DCD21FB64> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff87178000 -     0x7fff87255fef  libsystem_c.dylib (763.13.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <41B43515-2806-3FBC-ACF1-A16F35B7E290> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff87256000 -     0x7fff87264fff  com.apple.NetAuth (3.2 - 3.2) <F0D60E34-37A9-308D-B44E-E3450906173A> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetAuth.framework/Versions/A/NetAuth
    0x7fff87265000 -     0x7fff8726dfff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (??? - ???) <584B321E-5159-37CD-B2E7-82E069C70AFB> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff8727b000 -     0x7fff873e2ff7  com.apple.CFNetwork (520.5.3 - 520.5.3) <1C11C214-1C70-3358-A709-69C84D999DB8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
    0x7fff87ec4000 -     0x7fff87f37fff  libstdc++.6.dylib (52.0.0 - compatibility 7.0.0) <6BDD43E4-A4B1-379E-9ED5-8C713653DFF2> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
    0x7fff87f57000 -     0x7fff87ff9fff  com.apple.securityfoundation (5.0 - 55116) <70CDC3ED-39AA-3784-8715-F0F5E2CB9754> /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/SecurityFoundation
    0x7fff880f5000 -     0x7fff880f5fff  libOpenScriptingUtil.dylib (??? - ???) <A7847713-F410-39C0-884F-A7188A18E742> /usr/lib/libOpenScriptingUtil.dylib
    0x7fff88139000 -     0x7fff8842eff7  com.apple.security (7.0 - 55148.6) <4535E500-973A-3BA7-AF65-DF5CF0658F02> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
    0x7fff8845f000 -     0x7fff8846cff7  libbz2.1.0.dylib (1.0.5 - compatibility 1.0.0) <DFAB8CA8-CC9D-3F58-8C12-CE120442AACD> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
    0x7fff884ba000 -     0x7fff88508fff  libauto.dylib (??? - ???) <D8AC8458-DDD0-3939-8B96-B6CED81613EF> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff88509000 -     0x7fff88518fff  libxar.1.dylib (??? - ???) <9E05C939-6CBF-38E7-8915-86278F7DB6C7> /usr/lib/libxar.1.dylib
    0x7fff89127000 -     0x7fff891c2fff  com.apple.PackageKit (2.0.3 - 173) <2D37EB54-BFC7-3731-A27E-9BDE3211FE31> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PackageKit.framework/Versions/A/PackageKit
    0x7fff891c5000 -     0x7fff891ccfff  libcopyfile.dylib (85.1.70 - compatibility 1.0.0) <E805FDF4-7098-3F9F-BF27-191E3E0A0F10> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fff891cd000 -     0x7fff891dfff7  libz.1.dylib (1.2.5 - compatibility 1.0.0) <30CBEF15-4978-3DED-8629-7109880A19D4> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff891e0000 -     0x7fff89263fef  com.apple.Metadata (10.7.0 - 627.37) <B9BEB598-B6F2-3BFF-A8F3-C3C87CD076AB> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
    0x7fff89318000 -     0x7fff89326ff7  com.apple.AppleFSCompression (37 - 1.0) <61113C2F-564C-3E6C-918C-3179980D599F> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleFSCompression.framework/Versions/A/AppleFSCompression
    0x7fff893ac000 -     0x7fff89446ff7  com.apple.SearchKit (1.4.0 - 1.4.0) <4E70C394-773E-3A4B-A93C-59A88ABA9509> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
    0x7fff89447000 -     0x7fff89448fff  libunc.dylib (24.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <337960EE-0A85-3DD0-A760-7134CF4C0AFF> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
    0x7fff89960000 -     0x7fff89a01ff7  com.apple.LaunchServices (480.42 - 480.42) <A69F9426-05CE-3312-89FD-BC063DA66DBF> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
    0x7fff89a9b000 -     0x7fff89a9bfff  libkeymgr.dylib (23.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <61EFED6A-A407-301E-B454-CD18314F0075> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fff89a9c000 -     0x7fff89aa2ff7  libunwind.dylib (30.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <1E9C6C8C-CBE8-3F4B-A5B5-E03E3AB53231> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff89e6e000 -     0x7fff8a042ff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.7.2 - 635.21) <62A3402E-A4E7-391F-AD20-1EF20236CE1B> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff8a600000 -     0x7fff8a670fff  com.apple.datadetectorscore (3.0 - 179.4) <4AB32B7F-8EC2-327E-BAC8-80129AA36E7B> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/Versions/A/DataDetectorsCore
    0x7fff8a6cc000 -     0x7fff8a6d2fff  com.apple.DiskArbitration (2.4.1 - 2.4.1) <CEA34337-63DE-302E-81AA-10D717E1F699> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
    0x7fff8a7d6000 -     0x7fff8a7dbfff  libpam.2.dylib (3.0.0 - compatibility 3.0.0) <D952F17B-200A-3A23-B9B2-7C1F7AC19189> /usr/lib/libpam.2.dylib
    0x7fff8a7dc000 -     0x7fff8a7ddfff  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (??? - ???) <3DCF577B-F126-302B-BCE2-4DB9A95B8598> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
    0x7fff8a7de000 -     0x7fff8a7dfff7  libsystem_blocks.dylib (53.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <8BCA214A-8992-34B2-A8B9-B74DEACA1869> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fff8aa83000 -     0x7fff8aab0fe7  libSystem.B.dylib (159.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <6E5C8AC3-DBB7-31CB-BEB7-D6ED8E6DE0CE> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff8aab1000 -     0x7fff8ab95ff7  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices (478.50 - 478.50) <3D6AA4EF-C601-36C7-8F3A-A00964F01759> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
    0x7fff8ac6f000 -     0x7fff8ac82ff7  libCRFSuite.dylib (??? - ???) <0B76941F-218E-30C8-B6DE-E15919F8DBEB> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
    0x7fff8af44000 -     0x7fff8af45fff  libdnsinfo.dylib (395.11.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <853BAAA5-270F-3FDC-B025-D448DB72E1C3> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
    0x7fff8b3a1000 -     0x7fff8b3b0ff7  libxar-nossl.dylib (??? - ???) <A6ABBFB9-E4ED-38AD-BBBB-F9958B9CEFB5> /usr/lib/libxar-nossl.dylib
    0x7fff8b3c8000 -     0x7fff8b3cffff  com.apple.NetFS (4.0 - 4.0) <433EEE54-E383-3505-9154-45B909FD3AF0> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
    0x7fff8b3d0000 -     0x7fff8b43bff7  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0 - ???) <FE838BB6-D42E-3291-A1A0-6F53FC970261> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x7fff8b465000 -     0x7fff8b56cfe7  libsqlite3.dylib (9.6.0 - compatibility 9.0.0) <EE02BB01-64C9-304D-9719-A35F5CD6D04C> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
    0x7fff8b614000 -     0x7fff8b644ff7  com.apple.DictionaryServices (1.2.1 - 158.3) <5E2EBBFD-D520-3379-A431-11DAA844B8D6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
    0x7fff8b8da000 -     0x7fff8b8e8ff7  libkxld.dylib (??? - ???) <01161870-E3B3-3F87-BA4A-0AA7A081F409> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
    0x7fff8bf18000 -     0x7fff8bf23ff7  libc++abi.dylib (14.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <8FF3D766-D678-36F6-84AC-423C878E6D14> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff8bfe8000 -     0x7fff8c02aff7  libcommonCrypto.dylib (55010.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <BB770C22-8C57-365A-8716-4A3C36AE7BFB> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff8c02b000 -     0x7fff8c047ff7  com.apple.GenerationalStorage (1.0 - 126.1) <509F52ED-E54B-3FEF-B3C2-759387B826E6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/Versions/A/GenerationalStorage
    0x7fff8c16c000 -     0x7fff8c1b8ff7  com.apple.SystemConfiguration (1.11.3 - 1.11) <131780ED-E8DD-3153-81F2-5FEC4F6554C2> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
    0x7fff8c2ab000 -     0x7fff8c2abfff  com.apple.CoreServices (53 - 53) <043C8026-8EDD-3241-B090-F589E24062EF> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
    0x7fff8c46d000 -     0x7fff8c4acfff  com.apple.AE (527.7 - 527.7) <B82F7ABC-AC8B-3507-B029-969DD5CA813D> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
    0x7fff8c64d000 -     0x7fff8c657ff7  liblaunch.dylib (392.39.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <8C235D13-2928-30E5-9E12-2CC3D6324AE2> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff8c7f9000 -     0x7fff8c7fbfff  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent (2.0 - 1) <1F31CAFF-C1C6-33D3-94E9-11B721761DDF> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
    0x7fff8c866000 -     0x7fff8c86bfff  libcache.dylib (47.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <1571C3AB-BCB2-38CD-B3B2-C5FC3F927C6A> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fff8c8a2000 -     0x7fff8c8bffff  libxpc.dylib (77.19.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <9F57891B-D7EF-3050-BEDD-21E7C6668248> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
    0x7fff8c90b000 -     0x7fff8c949fff  com.apple.bom (11.0 - 183) <F300B9EC-995E-33A7-9175-9F07D4B68F16> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Versions/A/Bom
    0x7fff8c94a000 -     0x7fff8c955ff7  com.apple.bsd.ServiceManagement (2.0 - 2.0) <D836A22C-BBDC-3C9F-83D3-F8CC0EE75885> /System/Library/Frameworks/ServiceManagement.framework/Versions/A/ServiceManagement
    0x7fff8cc84000 -     0x7fff8ce86fff  libicucore.A.dylib (46.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <0176782F-9526-3905-813A-7A5676EC2C86> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff8ce87000 -     0x7fff8ce8bfff  libmathCommon.A.dylib (2026.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <FF83AFF7-42B2-306E-90AF-D539C51A4542> /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
    0x7fff8ce8c000 -     0x7fff8ce9afff  libdispatch.dylib (187.10.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <8E03C652-922A-3399-93DE-9EA0CBFA0039> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff8cf7c000 -     0x7fff8d07efff  libxml2.2.dylib (10.3.0 - compatibility 10.0.0) <AFBB22B7-07AE-3F2E-B88C-70BEEBFB8A86> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
    0x7fff8dc7c000 -     0x7fff8dc7dff7  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (??? - ???) <5459F293-E1F2-33B3-B9B2-2ABB7B915B62> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff8dc82000 -     0x7fff8dcf8ff7  libc++.1.dylib (28.4.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <A24FC3DA-4FFA-3DD2-9DCC-2B8D1B3BF97C> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff8e805000 -     0x7fff8e825fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib (1699.32.7 - compatibility 1.0.0) <66C9F9BD-C7B3-30D4-B1A0-03C8A6392351> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff8e826000 -     0x7fff8e827ff7  libremovefile.dylib (21.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <739E6C83-AA52-3C6C-A680-B37FE2888A04> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff8eb64000 -     0x7fff8eb65fff  liblangid.dylib (??? - ???) <CACBE3C3-2F7B-3EED-B50E-EDB73F473B77> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
    0x7fff901d6000 -     0x7fff90201ff7  libxslt.1.dylib (3.24.0 - compatibility 3.0.0) <E71220D3-8015-38EC-B97D-7FDB383C2BDC> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
    0x7fff90202000 -     0x7fff9051bfff  com.apple.Foundation (6.7.2 - 833.25) <22AAC369-B63C-3C55-8AC6-C3ECBA44DA7B> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
    0x7fff9051c000 -     0x7fff90529fff  com.apple.CrashReporterSupport (10.7.4 - 353) <6044CFB6-939E-3C73-BFBB-A8BBC096F135> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/Versions/A/CrashReporterSupport
    0x7fff90cde000 -     0x7fff90ce3ff7  libsystem_network.dylib (??? - ???) <5DE7024E-1D2D-34A2-80F4-08326331A75B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x7fff90d73000 -     0x7fff90d78fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib (6.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <98ECD5F6-E85C-32A5-98CD-8911230CB66A> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x7fff90d79000 -     0x7fff90d7dfff  libdyld.dylib (195.6.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <FFC59565-64BD-3B37-90A4-E2C3A422CFC1> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff90d7e000 -     0x7fff90d95fff  com.apple.CFOpenDirectory (10.7 - 146) <F321AE12-9592-3E56-AB8D-A47BA4696A0E> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFOpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/CFOpenDirectory
    0x7fff90d96000 -     0x7fff90e7ae5f  libobjc.A.dylib (228.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <871E688B-CF57-3BC7-80D6-F6476DFF109B> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff91d26000 -     0x7fff92042fff  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore (960.25 - 960.25) <4FC1AB30-022C-3C67-AC46-FDCBFCB7EEDE> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
    0x7fff92ce7000 -     0x7fff92cf0ff7  libsystem_notify.dylib (80.1.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <A4D651E3-D1C6-3934-AD49-7A104FD14596> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x7fff92d45000 -     0x7fff92d47fff  libquarantine.dylib (36.7.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <8D9832F9-E4A9-38C3-B880-E5210B2353C7> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 3
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=78.2M resident=46.0M(59%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=32.2M(41%)
Writable regions: Total=63.7M written=700K(1%) resident=992K(2%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=62.7M(98%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
MALLOC                             53.3M
MALLOC guard page                    32K
STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              10.0M
VM_ALLOCATE                          36K
__DATA                             3564K
__LINKEDIT                         49.1M
__TEXT                             29.1M
__UNICODE                           544K
mapped file                        15.7M
shared memory                        16K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             217.3
```

Comment: This ASC thread about the crsud daemon might shine some light on what is happening: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4891016?tstart=0  Do you have the built-in OS X firewall running?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's been turned off. Is it possible that its got something to do with apple software update -  Security update 2014-004? I managed to reinstall Lion seems ok for now. And I did not downloaded any security update, crsud is also not located in that directory yet.